# How to make my output text scrollable using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, text, scrollable

The text that I am trying to echo from `$data` is way too long and it is going off the screen beyond the boundaries of the table. In addition to that all the text is getting displayed without line breaks (or blank lines) or proper spacing.

My simple PHP code:

```
<div id="sampleid1" class="tabcontent" style="margin-left:48px;">
    <table width="510" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4" class="SampleClass">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo Sample1_LABEL;?>
            </td>
            <th align="left"><strong>:</strong>
            </th>
            <td>
                <?php echo $data[ 'Sample1'];?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo Sample2_LABEL;?>
            </td>
            <th align="left"><strong>:</strong>
            </th>
            <td>
                <?php echo $data[ 'Sample2'];?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In Summary:

1. I need the text that I am retrieving using the `$data` to get formatted in such a way that the line breaks are displayed in the output upon echoing.
2. I need that output text to be scrollable so no text will go off the screen beyond the boundaries.

Comment: do you mean the text does not wrap? Don't they contain spaces?

Comment: It's not a wrap issue but rather the text is way too long and it is getting off the screen (beyond the height of the screen) which is hindering the process of reading it. The text itself contains some empty/blank lines which are not getting displayed in the final output. Thanks for asking and i appreciate your help.

Comment: HTML treats all whitespace identically. 5 consecutive newlines will look the same as a single space. Within a `pre` tag, the behavior is different, and all whitespace is faithfully rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<td>
   <div style="height:100px; overflow:auto">
      <?php echo $data['Sample2'];?>
   </div>
</td>
```

You can also try

```
echo(nl2br($data['Sample2']));  //converts newline to <br /> html tag
```

Comment: That was brilliant! Thanks for taking the time to solve my query. The use of "nl2br" did solve my problem indeed. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

you need to set CSS to the TD tag where you echo that $data...

```
<td style="height:150px; overflow-y:scroll;">
```

My mistake.. TD dont accept overflow so you may do this::

```
<td style="height:150px"><div style="height:100%; overflow-y:scroll;">..PHPCODE...</div></td>
```

Comment: I have tried to use the overflow parameters as you said but it is not working for me. After i used the <pre> tag, the text started getting off the boundaries in both directions (x and y). I tried as well to restrict the height and width but it is ending all the same. (I am still trying with it now)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to correct the mistake and for all your help. You did mention something useful of course. (+1) for your good answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could echo a `<pre>` tag around output where whitespace is significant. Something like:

```
<?php echo "<pre>".Sample1_LABEL."</pre>";?>
```